# Probability distribution mean and variance

Tags: probability

> $3$ bad eggs are mixed with $7$ good eggs. $3$ eggs are drawn at random. Find the mean and variance of probability distribution of bad eggs.

Aren't these Bernoulli trials?

Comment: No, because the trials are not independent.  Drawing a good one increases the probability that the next one is bad.

Comment: What if I choose a particular egg and then replace it?Then the probability of drawing a particular egg becomes the same everytime I draw an egg.Then it becomes a Bernoulli trial.Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you replace then it is Bernoulli.

Comment: If it's not particularly given I have to take it as it is not replaced?

Comment: Your questioning is legitimate. Missed are the words "with replacement" or "without replacement. The context makes me suspect that it must be "without".

Comment: I think the phrasing of the problem clearly suggests that there is no replacement.  If I ask you to take three eggs out of a carton, I would be very surprised to see you take one, replace it, and so on.  So I think this is a no-replacement problem.  But of course you should clarify with your instructor.

Comment: Fair enough.  People tend to write probability and combinatorics problems informally, using ordinary language.  You are correct that this leads to a lot of confusion.  For instance, people write "find the probability of getting $N$ successes..." and half the time they mean "exactly $N$" and half the time they mean "at least $N$".

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$
\begin{array}{c|l|c}
X (\# \ of \ bad) & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ P(X) & P(X) \\
\hline
0 & P(GGG)= \frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9}\cdot \frac{5}{8} & \frac{210}{720} \\
1 & P(BGG)+P(GBG)+P(GGB) =\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{7}{9}\cdot \frac{6}{8}+\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{3}{9}\cdot \frac{6}{8}+\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9}\cdot \frac{3}{8} & \frac{378}{720} \\
2 & P(BBG)+P(BGB)+P(GBB) =\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9}\cdot \frac{7}{8}+\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{7}{9}\cdot \frac{2}{8}+\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{3}{9}\cdot \frac{2}{8} & \frac{126}{720} \\
3 & P(BBB)=\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{8} & \frac{6}{720} 
\end{array}
$$
Hence:
$$\begin{align} E(X)= & \sum XP(X)=\frac{0+378+252+18}{720}=\frac{648}{720}=\frac{9}{10}=0.9.\\
Var(X)= & \sum (X-E(X))^2P(X)= \\
= & \frac{9^2}{10^2}\cdot \frac{210}{720}+\frac{1^2}{10^2}\cdot \frac{378}{720}+\frac{11^2}{10^2}\cdot \frac{126}{720}+\frac{21^2}{10^2}\cdot \frac{6}{720}=\frac{49}{100}.\end{align}$$
$$$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that here the eggs are drawn without replacement. Hence it should be an [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Combinatorial_identities). So, if $3$ eggs are drawn  then, for $0\leq k\leq 3$,
$$p_k:=P(\mbox{number of bad eggs}=k)=\frac{\binom{3}{k}\binom{7}{3-k}}{\binom{10}{3}}.$$
It follows that 
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^3 kp_k=\frac{21}{10}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\mbox{Var}(X)=\sum_{k=0}^3 (k-E(X))^2p_k=\frac{49}{100}.$$

Comment: What if it was a Bernoulli distribution then

Comment: Is P(X=0)=(probability of drawing a good egg) ^10

Comment: Considering X as event of drawing a bad egg

Comment: @Abhijith Dileep Kumar Then the link changes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: When I use the hypergeometric distribution, I obtain $$E(X) = \sum_{k = 0}^{3} kp_k = 0\frac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}} + 1\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}} + 2\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}} + 3\frac{\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{9}{10}$$